Error message "Unhandled Runtime Error " NextJs
I am using prisma and supabase to create a store database. I keep running into this issue when making database queries:
"Error:
Invalid prisma.user.count() invocation:
Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(PostgresError { code: "26000", message: "prepared statement "s4" does not exist", severity: "ERROR", detail: None, column: None, hint: None }), transient: false })"
I think it has something to do with the number of queries I am making but can't find anything is supabase docs about this issue.

Please share an example of what queries you are trying. Also, the schema file and how you set up your DB connection. It's impossible to assist you without more information.

Checkout this issue on Github, it solved the problem for me:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/22837
